# v-for с vuex когда рендеришь формы в цикле

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuex

В доке vuex очень мало сказано про то, как нам его использовать с v-for. По крайней мере, для меня этого не достаточно, чтоб понять, как действовать в моем случае. 
Итак, у меня есть следующий UI:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поясню, что тут происходит. При каждом нажатии на кнопку `Добавить сообщение` появляется еще одна форма, где можно выбрать язык (список из `{name: ... ,id: ...}` объектов через [этот](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/) плагин), тайтл, текст и картинка. Я уже нажал два раза. У меня появилось две формочки. Этот функционал планируется к использованию неоднократно, потому я сделал его отдельным компонентом. Я планирую сохранять эти "сообщения", которые создаются на формочках в vuex. Этот компонент у меня часть большого компонента, который называется "Рассылка". При заходе на страницу, где рендерится Рассылки, ее данные приходят с сервера. Я не использую vue роутер, а осуществляю маршрутизацию по приложению средствами сервера, следовательно, на каждую страницу у меня новый стейт. Я собираюсь в компоненте Рассылки инициировать vuex данными, в том числе, установить туда эти "сообщения". Но тут уже v-model, как с локальным стейтом, не сработает. А как мне заставить отрендериться в дочернем компоненте эти данные сразу после того, как я инициирую vuex, причем, без костылей на ватчерах и красиво, я не представляю себе.

В данный момент компонент работает с локальным стейтом и это хорошо работает на create. Но вот с update я похоже облажался. Чуит мое сердце, что можно как то легко сделать. Но не догоняю, как. Я приведу здесь код компонента, упростив все, что связано с созданием картинок. Это сейчас не так важно.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" @click.prevent="createNewMessage">
            <i class="fa fa-language"/> Добавить сообщение
        </button>

        <div>
            <div v-for="(message, index) in messages">
                <b-button v-b-toggle="`collapse-${index}`" class="m-1">
                    <span v-if="message.title.trim().length > 0">Развернуть/свернуть {{ message.title}}</span>
                    <span v-else><i class="fa fa-mouse-pointer"/> Развернуть/свернуть сообщение</span>
                </b-button>
                <button class="btn btm-sm btn-danger" @click="deleteMessage(index, message)"><i class="fa fa-remove"/>
                </button>

                <b-collapse collapsed :id="`collapse-${index}`">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="typo__label">Выбирите языки</label>
                            <multiselect
                                    v-model="message.languages"
                                    :options="getLanguagesOptions"
                                    :multiple="true"
                                    :close-on-select="true"
                                    :clear-on-select="false"
                                    :preserve-search="true"
                                    placeholder="Выбирите языки"
                                    label="name"
                                    track-by="id"
                            >
                            </multiselect>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title" class="typo__label">Заголовок пуш-уведомления</label>
                            <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"
                                   v-model="message.title">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="text" class="typo__label">Текст пуш-уведомления</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="text" v-model="message.text"/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div id="upload-image">
                                <div v-if="!message.imageSrc">
                                    <h2>Выбирите картинку</h2>
                                    <input type="file" ref="file" @change="onFileChange($event, message)">
                                </div>
                                <div v-else>
                                    <img :src="message.imageSrc" alt="картинка"/>
                                    <button @click.prevent="removeImage($event, message)">Удалить</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr class="mb-2">
                    </form>
                </b-collapse>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {mapActions, mapMutations, mapState, mapGetters} from "vuex";
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        async created() {
            // список языков типа [{name: "русский", id: 1}, ... ] получается именно в этом компоненте 
            let res = (await axios.post(this.urlForGettingLanguagesFromServerProp)).data;
            this.$store.commit('setLanguagesOptions', res);

        },
        name: "MessageComponent",
        props: {
            urlForGettingLanguagesFromServerProp: String,
            uploadImageUrl: String,
            deleteImageUrl: String,
            selectedLanguagesIdsProp: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => []
            },
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapMutations(['setLanguagesSelected']),
            createNewMessage: function () {
                let message = {
                    languages: [],
                    languagesIds: [],
                    title: "",
                    text: "",
                    imageSrc: "",
                    imageDbId: 0
                };
                this.messages.push(message);
            },
            deleteMessage: function (index, message) {
                this.removeImage("", message);
                this.messages.splice(index, 1);
            },

            onFileChange: async function (e, message) {
                ...
            },
            removeImage: function (event, message) {
                ...
            }
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['getLanguagesOptions', 'getMessages'])
        },
        watch: {
            messages: {
                deep: true,
                immediate: true,
                handler(val, oldVal) {
                    let message = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val));
                    this.$store.commit("setMessages", message);
                }
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                messages: [],
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Еще раз, кратко. Есть большой родительский компонент. В него встраивается тот компонент, код которого приведен выше. Этот компонент генерит формочки по клику на кнопку. Я хочу привязать v-for, который отрисовывает формочки в этом компоненте к vuex. Так, чтоб при заполнении vuex в родительском компоненте, в дочернем все отрисовалось. Как лучше то сделать?

Answer (score 1):

> А как мне заставить отрендериться в дочернем компоненте эти данные сразу после того, как я инициирую vuex, причем, без костылей на ватчерах и красиво, я не представляю себе.

Например так:

У тебя есть:

```
<div v-for="(message, index) in messages">
```

и есть:

```
computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['getLanguagesOptions', 'getMessages'])
        },
```

Можно сделать получение данных напрямую через `...mapGetters` 
Детали можно найти [в документации](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/getters.html#%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5n%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-mapgetters).

```
computed: {
-            //...mapGetters(['getLanguagesOptions', 'getMessages']),
+            ...mapGetters(['getLanguagesOptions']),
+            ...mapGetters({
+              messages: 'getMessages',
+            },
data() {
            return {
-                messages: [], // при использовании ...mapGetters становится не нужен
            }
        }
```

В этом случае в шаблон данные попадут сразу после изменения в сторе.

На счет обновление не должно возникнуть проблем. Диспач данные по кнопке "создать" остальное сделает Vuex.